# ImportError: Module not found but sys.path is showing the file resides under the path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I print sys.path in my code I get the following as output:

['C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases', 'C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\TC-Regression', 'C:\Python27\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Python27\lib', etc.]

Now, when I write "import testCaseBase as TCB" where testcaseBase.py is in this path:

C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\Common\shared

I get an error: "**ImportError: No module named testCaseBase"**

My code is in C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\TC-Regression\regression.py. My code goes ahead with compilation, but testcaseBase.py which is residing in a parallel directory fails to compile.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but this file path...

```
C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\Common\shared
```

...isn't in your `sys.path`, so it's not surprising you got an error. You have several options though. Changing your project structure or, if `Common` and `shared` are actual packages with `__init__.py` defined inside of them, do:

```
import Common.shared.testCaseBase
```

You can also just append the path in your calling script, so:

```
sys.path.append('\SVTestcases\Common\shared')
```

Or, actually just add the following path to your ENV variable (`PYTHONPATH`)

```
C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\Common\shared
```

But it's not necessarily a good habit to substitute good directory structure and importing techniques with editing your `PYTHONPATH` each time. You'll be much better off if you resolve this another way.

Comment: Thanks Eithos, appending the path in sys.path worked for me, I am going to try other solutions given by you too

Comment: @user3565150: For more info on how to set up a package structure see the official Python docs on [Packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). That link's for Python 2, here's the [Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 2):

put

**C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\Common\shared**

in your PYTHONPATH env

Comment: I don't use Windows, but shouldn't that be `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: So, if there is another folder under Common, I have to put it in PATH env explicitly or just adding till common will include all the subfolders under it ?

Answer (score 1):

Please dont use ~/ in the path . it does not work. Use the full path.